# Flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build from onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, setstate

I am trying to show a dialog when someone clicks on the trailing icon of a ListTile but I am getting the "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build" error message. Here are the cards (in a MyCard class) and the function which is giving me the error message (checkCard):

```
static Widget buildCard(MyCard card, BuildContext context) {
    var dateFormat = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
    return Column(
      children: [
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Text(dateFormat.format(card.createdOn.toDate()))),
        const SizedBox(height: 6),
        ListTile(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          tileColor: Colors.white,
          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(card.subCategory)),
          title: Text("Score: " + card.score + " Misses: " + card.misses),
          subtitle: card.comment.isNotEmpty
              ? Text("Comment(s): " + card.comment)
              : null,
          trailing: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onPressed: checkCard(card, context)),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 18),
      ],
    );
  }

  static checkCard(MyCard card, BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => const Text("Hello"));
  }
```

and they get built from StatefulWidgets as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: MyCard.getData(3, Utils.ddfDropdown)!
            .whenComplete(() => setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                })),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
            return FutureBuilder<List<MyCard>>(
                future: MyCard.readData(snapshot.data),
                builder: (context, cards) {
                  if (cards.hasData) {
                    final card = cards.data!;
                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        itemCount: card.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return MyCard.buildCard(card[index], context); //Cards being built here
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
```

I looked up this error elsewhere; one suggestion was to do the following:

```
static checkCard(MyCard card, BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => const Text("Hello"));
    });
  }
```

but it seems like doing that calls the showDialog without having to click on the trailing IconButton and the screen then simply goes black.
Another suggestion was to do something like:

```
static checkCard(MyCard card, BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => const Text("Hello"));
    });
  }
```

but the same thing happens (it seems like showDialog gets called without having to click and the screen goes black).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming from, calling the method while building the widget.

```dart
  onPressed: checkCard(card, context)),
```

You like to call the method when it is pressed, so it can be

```dart
  onPressed:()=> checkCard(card, context)),
```